# Blending issues with simple particles

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I draw the particles in my game as a capsule (Two GL_POINTS, two GL_TRIANGLES).  Everything is nicely batched so that I draw the triangles first, then the points second (two draw calls total).

My problem is that in OpenGL es you have to round GL_POINTS yourself, and I have been doing it like this in the fragment shader.

```
precision highp float;

varying float outColor;

vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 circCoord = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( hsv2rgb( vec3(outColor / 360.0, 1.0, 1.0) ) , step(dot(circCoord, circCoord), 1.0) );
}
```

The problem is I also need to do depth sorting, because a particle is drawn in two separate draw calls sometimes the z position is not correct without depth buffering because they are drawn in two draw calls.

Now that I have the depth buffer going, and the rounded points they are not mixing well, and instead of having rounded particles they have a black area around them.  Any ideas?

Some extra notes:
I am doing ios opengl es (tile based deferred rendering I believe)

Each particle is initially defined as two points, the current location and the location it was in last frame.  These two points are drawn with GL_POINTS later.  Then the rectangle part is made with two triangles decided by finding a vector perpendicular to the vector of the two points.

Also the particles are already sorted in front to back order.  Technically their z position is arbitrary, I just need them to be intact.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you're using desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES.

Comment: @NicolBolas I added that into the post.  Did that make sense?

Comment: I would start by use of depth test condition which accept also equal Z-coordinates but that will not entirely resolve Z-fighting. Then I would eliminate the second draw call and render all in single pass. For that you need to change your shader so if you are near middle of triangle render your point instead. Without knowing what you are trying to do is this just guess work. Add some sample images. In case you can not get rid of the second draw then render the points with some offset in Z-axis of camera space (do it inside vertex shader) but that will not work if your triangles intersect alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also the particles are already sorted in front to back order. Technically their z position is arbitrary, I just need them to be intact.

I suspect that's your problem.

Points are square. You can fiddle the blending to make them appear round, but the geometry (and hence the depth value) is still square. Things behind the point are being Z-failed by the corners which are outside of the coloured round region.

The only fix to this without changing your algorithm completely is either use a triangle mesh rather than a point (so the actual geometry is round), or `discard` fragments in the fragment shader for point pixels which are outside of the round region you want to keep.

Note that using `discard` in shaders can be relatively expensive, so check the performance of that approach ...

Comment: I did some research on that.  Turns out Apple devices use a differed rendering pipeline, which causes the problem in the first place.  I tried out using discards based on dot products of the fragment position and that worked, surprisingly with a tolerable amount of latency! It is possible that when I port this to android the situation will be different.